# Breaking out of for each loop javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have an object here called computedJobs,

```js
{
  'a': [{'_id': '1'}, {'_id': '2'}, {'_id': '3'} ],
  'b': [{'_id': '4'}]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, trying to delete an object with the '_id' as '1'.

So what my initial thought was, to loop through it and then when I find the item I break out and delete that item. This is what I have written,

```js
var res;
          for (var key in this.computedJobs) {
            for(var i=0; i<this.computedJobs[key].length; i++) {
              console.log(this.computedJobs[key])
              if (this.computedJobs[key][i]._id === '1') {
                res = this.computedJobs[key][i]
                break
              }
            }
          }
```

But the `res` comes as undefined.

On the other hand, I had tried,

```js
var res;
          for (var key in this.computedJobs) {
            this.computedJobs[key].forEach(j => {
              if (j._id === '1') {
                res = j
                break
              }
            })
          }
```

But I get an error `Syntax Error: Unsyntactic break`. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: break is valid in a `for...` loop ... you are not inside such a loop, since you are in a function. try using Array `find` method, since that's what you are doing anyway, finding a single element

Comment: though, referencing the found object won't allow you to delete it

Comment: As Bravo pointed out, you are actually in a function.  There are much better ways of handling this situation, but instead of break, try return instead.

Comment: Would making the outer loop a for loop as well solve the problem? Something like `for (var ix = 0; i< this().keys.length; ix++) ...` in that case the break should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for a fact that you have at most 1 matching "object", you can use [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and `splice` the object out of the array

```js
var data = {
  'a': [{'_id': '1'}, {'_id': '2'}, {'_id': '3'} ],
  'b': [{'_id': '4'}]
};
Object.values(data).some(v => v.some(({_id}, index, array) => {
    console.log(_id);
    if (_id === '1') {
        return array.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
}));
console.log(data);
```

By using Array#some, the iteration stops as soon as a truthy value is returned from the callback - so you can see, the only tested object is the one you want to remove - quick and efficient, no unnecessary iterations

Let's see what happens if we delete id 5

```js
var data = {
  'a': [{'_id': '1'}, {'_id': '2'}, {'_id': '3'} ],
  'b': [{'_id': '4'}, {'_id': '5'}, {'_id': '6'}]
};
Object.values(data).some(v => v.some(({_id}, index, array) => {
    console.log(_id);
    if (_id === '5') {
        return array.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
}));
console.log(data);
```

### You can see it

> The code below probably isn't what you need - but included just in case

If there can be multiple objects with same ID, then it's a little more complex

I use `reduceRight` as a convenient way of functionally iterating through an array from end to start, as that's how you want to do it if you're mutating the array

```js
var data = {
  'a': [{'_id': '1'}, {'_id': '2'}, {'_id': '3'} ],
  'b': [{'_id': '4'}]
};
Object.values(data).forEach(v => v.reduceRight((_, {_id}, index, array) => {
    if (_id === '1') {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}, null));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find the index of the object and splice the array.

```
var index = this.computedJobs[key].findIndex(j => j._id === '1');
if ( index >= 0 ) {
  this.computeJobs.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and made minimal changes required:

```
let objToDelete =   {
                    'a': [{'_id': '1'}, {'_id': '2'}, {'_id': '3'} ],
                    'b': [{'_id': '4'}]
                  };
var res =   {};                 
for (var key in objToDelete) {
   for(var i=0; i<objToDelete[key].length; i++) {
     if (objToDelete[key][i]._id === '1') {
       res = objToDelete[key][i];
       break;
     }
   }
}

if(Object.keys(res).length && res.hasOwnProperty('_id')){
    console.log('Yes we got the element!');
}
else{
    console.log('Object not found!');
}

console.log(res)
```

And it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
const jsonObj = {
  'a': [{'_id': '1'}, {'_id': '2'}, {'_id': '3'} ],
  'b': [{'_id': '4'}]
};

let result;
const keys = Object.keys(jsonObj);

keys.forEach(k => {
  const obj = jsonObj[k].find(o => o._id === '1');
  if (obj) return result = obj;
});
console.log('Result: ', result);
```